# How do get consistent Word cell border sizes

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I'm trying to get consistent cell border sizes, but am having difficultly doing so.  I'm used to the simplicity of HTML tables and cell.

I have three tables:

1. two-column, multi-row table (orange) - acts as a container for other tables; border will be hidden in final version; margin (white space) should be 0.08" on each size of #2
2. one-column, one-row table (red) - provides a colored border for #3 with a 0.04" margin on each size of #3
3. one-column, three-row table (green) - the content

[image]

Problems:

1. green table should always be the width of #2 (less the margins); it isn't
2. there should be a margin between green and red table; there isn't
3. orange table should always have a consistent top and bottom margin; I had to manually size the row

Questions:

1. is there an auto-size feature would size the red table to the interior margin of the orange table?  same with the green table?
2. for my purposes, is it better to use `default cell margins` or `default cell spacing`?
3. is there a trick to grab the table handles [+]?  they disappear when the mouse approaches them.

Answer (score 0):

1. To autosize a table within a table, right-click and choose "Autofit"-> "Autofit to Window".  This will expand the table horizontally to the size of its container (and retain margins).
2. I would think Cell Margins are more flexible as you can pick which direction.  Cell spacing is 1 size in all directions
3. For the handle to stay up, hover or click inside the table, then head to the handle (staying inside the table on your way there).